# 301 redirects dynamic URL's htacces

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm having trouble figuring 301 redirecting this.

Old site has a structure like this for subcategories:

www.domain.com/?someid=1&**pageload=serieslist**&someparam=1

What I would like to do is redirect some of the subcategories to new categories 1:1, and then the rest to new domain root.

Will it work doing it like this, first listing all 1:1 redirects, and then a "catch all" for the rest?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Redirect 301 /?someid=1&pageload=serieslist&someparam=1 http://www.newdomain.com/category1/    
Redirect 301 /?someid=2&pageload=serieslist&someparam=1 http://www.newdomain.com/category2/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pageload=serieslist$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.dk/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `Redirect` directive to match query string. Use it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} someid=1&pageload=serieslist&someparam=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.newdomain.com/category1/? [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} someid=2&pageload=serieslist&someparam=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.newdomain.com/category2/? [L,R=302]    

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)pageload=serieslist(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.dk/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Ahh my bad. The standard redirects was meant to be 1:1 redirects, without the stars included (copy/paste mistake).

But ofc it's better using your solution, except it should be 301 instead of 302. Thanks, I'll try it out.

Comment: Yes I used 302 only for testing, once it works just change it to 301. Let me know how it goes.